# Why is the movie titled "Fracture"?

Tags: title, fracture

Why is the movie titled "[Fracture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_(2007_film))"?

I watched the movie but couldn't find anything related to Fracture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the movie's IMDb trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488120/faq):

> **What does the title have to do with the movie?**
>
> The title comes from a scene in which Crawford tells Willy about his
>   first experience candling eggs (holding an egg up to the light of a
>   candle and looking for imperfections) on his grandfather's egg farm.
>   'He told me to put all the eggs that were cracked or flawed into a
>   bucket for the bakery,' he explains. 'He came back an hour later, and
>   there were 300 eggs in the bakery bucket...I had found a flaw in every
>   single one of them...thin places in the shell and fine hairline
>   cracks. You look closely, enough,' he goes on, 'and you find that
>   everything has a weak spot where it can break sooner or later.' He
>   then assures Willy that he has already found his weak spot, his crack,
>   the hairline fracture of his character. 'You're a winner, Willy,'
>   Crawford concludes.